# Fetch selected item of DropDownList using $(this) object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

How do I fetch the selected item of a `DropDownList` using `$(this)`?

I have two DropDownLists in a web page. I want to get the selected item name. I tried 3 ways and each gave different result.

1. This method showed the selected-item in "1st list" and also the selected-item of "2nd list". I guess this is because selector was not qualified with the ID.
2. This method gave proper result. Can I achieve the same result using $(this), instead of ID. I guess the THIS object will be pointing to html-element.
3. This method gave no results

   ```
   $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
             $('#IdServerType').bind("change", LoadX);
        }
   );
   ```

.

```
function LoadX()
{
    var str = "";
    
    /////  1
    str = $("select option:selected").text(); 
    console.log('menu clicked: ' + str);

    /////  2
    str = $("#IdServerType option:selected").text();
    console.log('menu clicked: ' + str);

    /////  3
    str = $("this option:selected").text(); //3
    console.log('menu clicked: ' + str);
}
```

Please note I want to keep the event registration and event-handler separate; helps in code maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` with `children()` to get the selected `option` element.

```
str = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
```

`children('option:selected')` will select the selected `option` from the `select` element.